# Python regular expression to extract string from python dataframe

Tags: python, extract

I coded a PDF extraction through Python, and reading it into Python string. I am trying to extract data from different PDFs, and the structure for the addresses on each document is slightly different. Here is the example:

```
Alamat :Menara Bank Mega, Lantai 24, Jl. Kapten P Tendean
Kav. 12-14A

Alamat :JL USMAN NO. 42, RT 8/4, KEL. KELAPA DUA WETAN,
KEC. PASAR REBO, JAKARTA TIMUR

Alamat :JL. HR. RASUNA SAID KAV 1-2, GRAHA IRAMA
LANTAI 6 KUNINGAN TIMUR- SETIABUDI JAKARTA
SELATAN

Alamat :GD. GRAHA PRATAMA LT.10, JL. MT. HARYONO
KAV.15, TEBET

AHUAlamat :GEDUNG BERITASATU PLAZA LT. 8, JL. JEND. GATOT
SUBROTO KAV. 35-36
```

I expect to extract everything after the ":". Is there a regular expression to find all of the things on the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is one possible approach:

`(?:Alamat|AHUAlamat)`: is a non-capturing group which matches either "Alamat" or "AHUAlamat".
`\s*`: matches any number of whitespace characters.
`:`: matches the colon character.
`(.*)`: is a capturing group which matches any series of characters except newlines.

```py
import re

data_str = """Alamat :Menara Bank Mega, Lantai 24, Jl. Kapten P Tendean Kav. 12-14A
Alamat :JL USMAN NO. 42, RT 8/4, KEL. KELAPA DUA WETAN, KEC. PASAR REBO, JAKARTA TIMUR
Alamat :JL. HR. RASUNA SAID KAV 1-2, GRAHA IRAMA LANTAI 6 KUNINGAN TIMUR- SETIABUDI Jakarta SELATAN
Alamat :GD. GRAHA PRATAMA LT.10, JL. MT. HARYONO KAV.15, TEBET
AHUAlamat :GEDUNG BERITASATU PLAZA LT. 8, JL. JEND. GATOT SUBROTO KAV. 35-36
"""

pattern = r'(?:Alamat|AHUAlamat)\s*:(.*)'
addresses = data_str.splitlines()

for address in addresses:
    match = re.search(pattern, address)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1).strip())
```

**Note:** If every line of string have the same structure with `:` then `split()` alone can do the job:

```py
lst_data = data_str.splitlines()
addresses = [address.split(':')[-1] for address in lst_data]
print(*addresses, sep='\n')
```

---

```
Menara Bank Mega, Lantai 24, Jl. Kapten P Tendean Kav. 12-14A
JL USMAN NO. 42, RT 8/4, KEL. KELAPA DUA WETAN, KEC. PASAR REBO, JAKARTA TIMUR
JL. HR. RASUNA SAID KAV 1-2, GRAHA IRAMA LANTAI 6 KUNINGAN TIMUR- SETIABUDI Jakarta SELATAN
GD. GRAHA PRATAMA LT.10, JL. MT. HARYONO KAV.15, TEBET
GEDUNG BERITASATU PLAZA LT. 8, JL. JEND. GATOT SUBROTO KAV. 35-36
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is afer : and ends by blank line, so you can use this RegEx

```
/Alamat *:(((?!(\n\n|\r\n\r\n)).)*)/gms
```

[Online check](https://regex101.com/r/L1Zolx/1)